Quantitative version of law of large numbers and application to RH
Let $(X_i)_{i \in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence of independent RV's with zero means $\Bbb E[X_i]=0$ and let $(b_i)_{i \in \Bbb N}$ be an increasing sequence of positive numbers satisfying $\sum_i \Bbb E[X_i^2]/b_i^2 < \infty$.
Set $S_n:= \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$.
Question 1: How to see that $\varinjlim_{n \to \infty} P(S_n =o(b_n))=1$ (note here $o(b_n)$ uses the usual "little o" notation... this distinction becomes later very important)
#Edit: Presumably the author tacitly assumed additionally $b_n \to + \infty$; otherwise the claim would be wrong; compare with Thành Nguyễn's answer
This is claimed without proof in Lemma 8.3.2 (page 212) Algorithmic Number Theory: Efficient algorithms, Volume 1
This should be seen as a "quantitative version" of law of large numbers. Going through the usual proof of statement of "usual" LoLN I not found a way how to adapt this proof; it seems that there are different methods involved as basic assumpion differ, as eg $X_i$ are not assumed to be iid.
Question 2: Furthermore in what subsequently follows at same page, applying this lemma next to Riemann hypothesis by setting RV $X_k := T_k - 1 /\log \ k$ and $b_k :=k^{1/2+\epsilon}$, it not clear why one actually obtains as error term $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ and not $o(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$. Clearly latter is stronger as the former, but latter is not what Riemann hypothesis states, so this passing from $o$ to $O$ appears strange. Where in the argument from the linked book one actually passed from big O to small o.

The images are not accessible for me, but I can speculate on Question 2 anyway. Could the claim be that the error is $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$? If so, that’s equivalent to being $o(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$…

@Aphelli: Yes, that was exactly the claim, thanks! To work it a bit out, so what matters is really just that $\epsilon >0$: Then $f(x) =o(x^{{1/2} + \epsilon})$ reads definitionally as $f(x) /x^{{1/2} + \epsilon} \to 0$ for $x \to +\infty$, or equivalently that for all $\delta>0$ and $x > N(\delta)$ big enoughwe have $f(x) /x^{{1/2} + \epsilon} < \delta$, equivalently $f(x) /x^{{1/2}} < \delta \cdot x^{-\epsilon}$. But as $x^{-\epsilon}$ tends for big $x$ to zero, this is equivalent to the claim there exist a $M>0$ with $f(x) /x^{{1/2}} < M \cdot x^{-\epsilon}$ for $x >N(M)$ big engh.

So just a finite bound. But latter is by definition exactly what $f(x) =O(x^{{1/2} + \epsilon})$ says, that's what you claimed!

And so, if the primes would be randomly distributed, this would be the shortest proof of a millennium problem:) So, it stays an "almost surely" one. Nevertheless even due to latter reason it's a fake proof it appears to be a rather nice "motivation" for the real $1/2$- strip of zeta function as the quoted claim in analytic terms is equivalent to RH

Re your first comment, I just wanted to clarify one thing. The point is that in order to go from $O$ to $o$ you can choose a smaller $\epsilon$. If your error is in $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon >0$, then, for any given $\epsilon >0$, it is in $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon/2})$, and since $1/2+\epsilon/2 < 1/2+\epsilon$, then $x^{1/2+\epsilon/2} = o(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$.

I'll only answer the first question by adding an additional condition: $b_n \rightarrow +\infty$. What the book claims is the following:
$$
    1 = \mathbb{P}(S_n = o(b_n)) = \mathbb{P}(\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \text{ such that } \vert S_n \vert \le \epsilon b_n \ \forall n \ge n_0)
$$
Note that
$$
    \mathbb{P}(S_n = o(b_n)) = \mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{S_n}{b_n} = 0\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k = 0\right)
$$
So we need to show that
$$
    \dfrac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k \xrightarrow{\text{a.s}} 0
$$
The Kronecker's lemma implies that, (here ($b_n$) is an increasing, positive sequence with $\sup_n b_n = +\infty$ are needed)
$$
    \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{X_n}{b_n} \text{ converges a.s} \Longrightarrow \dfrac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k \xrightarrow{\text{a.s}} 0
$$
Using the fact that, $\mathbb{E}(X_k) = 0$ and $\sum_n \text{Var}(X_n/b_n) = \sum_n \mathbb{E}(X_n^2)/b_n^2 < \infty$, we can conclude that $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{X_n}{b_n}$ converges a.s by the Kolmogorov convergence criterion
